# release management with Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, release, azure-devops, ms-release-management

With VS Update 4, we can now use Release Management with Visual Studio Online.

With Release Management server : no problem. 
With Visual Studio Online : I can't manage to create a automated deployment.

My  process  always fail to "Deploy Step" with this log message "The given key was not present in the dictionary".
My environment is localized in different cloud service in Azure.

Do you have an idea of where the problem may come?
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjxuv.png]

Comment: Under your Azure settings, have you defined a valid storage container? RM has to upload the binaries that you're deploying into an Azure storage container.

Comment: I think Daniel Mann is on the right track. Review your Azure Subscription details. Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/using-release-management-vso-service-to-manage-releases.aspx

Comment: @Joerage I actually did a quick test, I don't think I was right... It won't let you save the Azure settings with an invalid storage account, and if you delete the storage account after you save the settings, you get a failure in the "predeploy" step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are not supporting standard environments in VSO as of now and from the error message (which is bad), it looks like you are trying to run a release on a standard environment.

Recently we have blocked creation of new standard environments but have not touched the existing standard environments.

Can you please try running a release on a VNext azure environment & share whether it works for you or not?

Comment: Miguel Pereira from my company was also facing the same issue. But he was not using the standard environment but the output of his build definition was set to a network share which again we don't support. On changing that to "copy build output to the server", it worked for him.